# Trying to edit a deleted post shows incorrect error message

Tags: bug, ios-app

I recently tried to edit a question on the iOS app, but it prompted me:

> Account is not allowed to suggest edits

as shown below:

[image: rejection reason]

The reason that I couldn't make the edit was because the question was deleted before submitting my edit.  I can't imagine that it would be correct because I can definitely make edits as I did recently:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23901032/2

I believe it would be more helpful to say:

> This question was deleted.  Therefore, edits are no longer accepted for this question.

<sub>I was using the Beta app when this occurred.  I am unsure if that was the problem here, but I figured I would post it just in case.</sub>